# Proving if $A$ is a null set and $B$ is a countable set then $A+B$ is null

Tags: measure-theory, integration

If $A$ is a null set and $B$ is a countable set, both in $\mathbb{R}$ can anyone help me show that $A+B$ is null.

So I'm slightly unsure of where to start here, but how about assuming that $A+B$ is not null. therefore there must exist an interval of real numbers in $A+B$, but that would be uncountable, contradiction. Am I along the right lines here?

Comment: Hint: If $A= \{ x_i \}_{i \in N}$, then $A+B= \cup_{i \in N} A+x_i$.. What can you say about a countable union of null sets?

Comment: Hint: write $A + B$ as a countable union of null sets in a natural way.

Comment: Hi again, N.S ;)

Comment: Hi again, LOL..

Comment: A simple example of a non-null set that does not contain any intervals would also be the set of all irrational numbers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where I went wrong :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $A + B = \{ a + b \mid a \in A , b \in B \} = \bigcup_{b \in B} b + A $

Then you have:

$$ \mu (A + B) \leq \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mu(b_i + A) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mu (A) = 0$$

Where the inequality follows from the countable subadditivity of $\mu$ and you have $\mu(b_i + A) = \mu(A)$ because the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant.

Comment: Thank you! both you and Arturo have given me perfect answers, but i'll give you the accept as you have less rep :)

Comment: @LHS That's very kind of you, thank you. Glad I could help. : )

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt will not work because it is false that a set of positive measure must contain an interval. If you are familiar with the Cantor set, there is a variation of the construction, giving what are called [fat Cantor sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Cantor_set). These sets contain no intervals, but have positive measure. (Or, as Dejan Govc notes, the set of all irrationals).

To prove the statement, note that $A+b$ is null and measurable for each $b\in B$. Since
$$A+B = \bigcup_{b\in B}(A+b)$$
and there are only countably many elements in $B$, it follows that
$$\mu(A+B) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{b\in B}(A+b)\right) \leq \sum_{b\in B}\mu(A+b).$$

Comment: Oh right I because we're only shifting the null set along it remains null.. you can really tell i've just been trying to teach myself all of this this evening..