# $A, B$ null sets implies $A+B$ is a null set?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A, B\subset \mathbb{R}$ be sets with lebesgue-measure $0$.
Define $A+B= \left \{ a+b: a\in A, b\in B  \right \}$.

So, is $A+B$ necessarily a null set?

I found [this obvious result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101146/proving-if-a-is-a-null-set-and-b-is-a-countable-set-then-ab-is-null) but nothing more. My intuition tells me that this isn't true, but I don't really manage to approach this problem.

Another question that raises is: is $A+B$ always measurable when $
A, B$ are measurable? Again, no definition of measurability helped me very much.

It's worth mentioning that I know that if A, B are measruable with positive measure, then $A+B$ contains an open interval.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using Cantor sets.

Comment: There is an answer here already: [A set with measure 0 has a translate containing no rational number](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1902794/a-set-with-measure-0-has-a-translate-containing-no-rational-number/1902823#1902823)